# no module named keras after installing keras

Tags: python, keras, module, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I'm using anaconda ver 3, and I have installed python as well separately from anaconda. I installed python ver 2.7 and ver 3.6 from python website.

Now, I have installed keras from anaconda command prompt by using conda install keras. However, when I open jupyter notebook and write :

```
import keras
```

it says :

```
no module named keras
```

I also tried importing tensorflow but it gave me the same error

Comment: You are probably not using the same python interpreter as the one installed by Anaconda

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro how to use the one installed by anaconda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know, keras is a version of tensorflow. You should try installing tensorflow instead and then run

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.__version__
```

if you get `'2.1.0'` or any 2., you should be all set!

EDIT1: Keras is part of tensorflow not a version (as pointed out in the comments).

EDIT2: The link below gives good details on environments activation/creation.

https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html

Comment: i've also installed tensorflow and it gave me the same error. I tried this too.

Comment: @JohnSall Hmmm... Maybe the conda environment isn't activated? Did you try running conda list to make sure it was there?

Comment: no, it isn't there. I just ran conda list and I couldn't find keras. now what?

Comment: Keras is not a version of TensorFlow, it is included inside of TensorFlow, which is completely different to "being" a version.

Comment: okay, it turned out the package tenserflow isn't in conda list because I didn't activate the environment. but now that I activated the environment and I can also see keras and tenserflow in conda list, I still have the same problem when I import them

Comment: @JohnSall It should be there if you can see it in the environment. The only thing I can think of would be that maybe your jupyter notebook is launched from outside of the environment?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so what I did is first updated anaconda by using :

```
conda update conda
```

and then I installed python :

```
conda install python=3.7
```

and finally I installed keras again :

```
conda install keras
```

And now I can import both packages of keras and tenserflow